# mysqldump access denied

Tags: mysql

When I try to backup using mysqldump from ssh,
I run the following command on machine 10.64.1.1. It gives the following error.

`mysqldump --user=test -p=password --host=10.64.1.2 --tab=. databasename tablename`

`mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'test'@'10.64.1.1' (using password: YES)` when trying to connect

However, I can access mysql using the same user and password.

`mysql --user=test -p[password]`

Current user:       `test@10.64.1.1`

SSL:            `Not in use`

Current pager:      `stdout`

Using outfile:      `''`

Using delimiter:    `;`

Server version:     `5.0.91-50-log Percona SQL Server, Revision 73 (GPL)`

Protocol version:   `10`

Connection:     `10.64.1.2 via TCP/IP`

Updates:

If I do following mysql document: `--password[=password]` or `-p[password]`.

Since my password contains special symbol `@`, Mysql cannot detect user correctly. It complains:

`mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that you would have to lose the = when using -p or do it with --password :

> --password[=password], -p[password]
>
> The password to use when connecting to
>   the server. If you use the short
>   option form (-p), you cannot have a
>   space between the option and the
>   password. If you omit the password
>   value following the --password or -p
>   option on the command line, you are
>   prompted for one. Specifying a
>   password on the command line should be
>   considered insecure. See Section 6.6,
>   "Keeping Your Password Secure".

Comment: I tried your method. It still complains. Since my password contains special symbol '@', it looks like 123@456. If I use your method, lose the = when using -p, mysql cannot detect user correctly. It shows: mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database.

Comment: it's not my method it's official mysqldump's documentation :) Have you tried --password with = symbol ?

Comment: Yes. I tried both. If I use the documentation method, --password[=password], or -p[password], mysql cannot detect user. It complains: mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database.

Comment: I see in your mysqldump you use a different host than when you connect to mysql. One is 10.64.1.2 and one is 10.64.1.1. Also, do you allow mysql remote connections ?

Comment: I think so. On machine 10.64.1.1, I run: mysql --user=test -p[password]. It works. I think the culprit is the special symbol @ in the password. How to deal with it?

Comment: it seems that you do mysqldump remotely though, since you pass a net routed host. Check your mysql conf file on whether remote connections are allowed.

Comment: I noticed that there is no "skip-networking" in my.cnf file. So it allows remote connections.

Comment: bind address is set ? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 51):

You have to run CMD.EXE as the Administrator:

Right click on cmd.exe --> Run as Administrator and then type your command:

mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] -h[ip or name] yourdatabasename > c:\sqlfile.sql

It should work fine.

Comment: This saved what is left of my hair!

Comment: Wow! Never thought running a command will be so difficult.

Answer (score 18):

I know the topic is very old, but I happened to have the same issue. I figured out that the problem was just the special character used in the password. In fact they must be escaped with the anti slash: `--password=123\@456` or using signle quotes `--password='123@456'`

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks for posting a different answer on old question! Had to add quotes when on Linux, but no quotes on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue for me as well. Ended up with `-p'P@$$W0RD'`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with a DB user created via Plesk. The user has permissions for a single database. If I specify the database name I get the error mentioned above. If I specify `-A` for all databases, the dump works.

Answer (score 7):

In windows, I resolved it by making a directory and then dumping *.sql  file in backup directory.

`C:\backup`

There are no issues with commands :
 Remove the [ ] square brackets

`mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] -h[ip] yourdb > C:\backup\sqlfile.sql`

It worked for me:)

Comment: I was having the same problem because I was trying to create de backup in C:\ buy when a change the filesystem route to other then It worked!

Answer (score 5):

One more possible cause can be the place you are trying to create dump.
Writing `mysqldump -u[username] -p yourdb > D:\backup\sqlfile.sql` instead of `mysqldump -u[username] -p yourdb > sqlfile.sql` resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `=` (equal sign) for the connection options. You want the following.

```
mysqldump -u test -ppassword -h 10.64.1.2 ...
```

Check out [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for more details on the other options.

Comment: and it's still doesn't work, as Tim said, when you specify DB name, i've got this error, exporting all DB's works fine

Comment: Note the *...*, you'll need to add the rest of the options.

Comment: `--password=foo` is the long form, `-pfoo` is the short form. Both are valid.

Comment: found solution - this error was caused because my user hadn't had permissions to lock table

Answer (score 0):

Heres what worked for me- run cmd line as admin.
dont put any password after -p, you are automatically prompted to enter a password and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Trying with this command

```
mysqldump --user=root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --databases database_name [database_name_2,...] > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there need additional access to create file in C:/ location so try to use other like for me it resolve by :
mysqldump -u root -p cricket classics > C:\Users\habib_s9ayvfl\Desktop\classics.sql

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with this page [https://dev.mysql.com/mysqldump-copying-database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-copying-database.html)
open your console window (like cmd) and navigate to your mysql installation folder. F.e. c:\mysql and then to the bin folder, so you have **c:\mysql\bin**

Then type:

```
mysqldump source_db_name -uuser_name -ppassword  > target_database.sql
```

Be sure that after -u there are no blanks! Same by -p! No blanks!
When you're done, type:

```
mysqladmin create target_database -uuser_name -ppassword
```

And now you can migrate the data from target_database.sql to your new database:

```
mysql target_database < target_database.sql -uuser_name -ppassword
```

It's a very "simple an stupid" way to cloning your database on a same server, into a new one. Also my description here is simple and stupid, but maybe it will be useful for someone someday :-)