# create mysql dumpfle on windows7 cmd mysql server 5.7

Tags: mysql, windows-7-x64, dump, mysql-5.7

I have a picture on the website below, which shows all tries I have done in vain.

[image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/14mu9ar.jpg]

What is the right way to create this dump file? I want to create it and later use it.

Comment: website -- http://oi58.tinypic.com/14mu9ar.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that user logger in system don't have write access to designated location.

Try to write a dump in Your profile folder in c:\users\YOUR_LOGIN_NAME

ex:

```
  mysqldump -uroot -proot derek > c:\users\matt\dump.sql
```

Comment: do you mean I should first create a file called dump or specifying a path in the instruction, I think I have specified the paths already

Comment: By default user cant write to directory "c:\program files", try to write dump to directory where logged user (system user) have write access - best in home directory.

Comment: I really don't know what to do, it failed when I tried to write it to the desktop

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand another problem that was going on. one answer from this page worked out for me..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767036/mysqldump-access-denied

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with authentication. Are you giving it the correct password? If you are, check if this user with this password is allowed to login from localhost. Information should be in the users table.

Comment: Yeah, I am giving it correct password. I login to mysql using user root and password root, and host 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password),

> - --password[=password], -p[password]
>
> The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the
>   short option form (-p), **you cannot have a space between the option and
>   the password**. If you omit the password value following the --password
>   or -p option on the command line, mysqldump prompts for one.

If your username is `root` and your password is `root`, change

```
mysqldump -u root -p root
```

to

```
mysqldump -u root -proot
```