# using mysqldump in cmd to backup database getting access denied

Tags: mysql

I am getting error (access denied) when trying to backup MySQL database using below query:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword testing > testing.sql
```

However, I was able to log in to MySQL using cmd with below query

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

so I am sure my username and password is not wrong. Can anyone help me why I am getting access denied in mysqldump?

Comment: open cmd as administrator ?

Comment: still access is denied :(

Comment: try to save in a different location i.e: C:\backup maybe you don't have permission to write to that location

Comment: thanks! that solved it. :)
wanna put is as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [mysqldump access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767036/mysqldump-access-denied)

You can try to

- run the CMD as adminstrator
- try to save the file in a different location (i.e: C:\backup)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your ip is not localhost,

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword -h "your ip" testing > testing.sql
```